# How to print increasing order in dictionary's?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program is a calorie counter that reads the food and calories from a text file and the name + the foods the person ate. At the end of the program it should output the names + total calories (starting with lowest first). The output values are printing correct, although they aren't in the correct order.

Anyone know why this is happening?

```
import sys
file = "foods.txt"
line = sys.stdin
fridge = {}
with open(file, "r") as f:
for a in f:
    a = a.strip().split()
    food = " ".join(a[:-1])
    calorie = a[-1]
    fridge[food] = calorie
for i in line:
    i = i.strip().split(",")
    name = i[0]
    foods = i[1:]
    total_calories = 0
    for k in foods:
        calorie = fridge.get(k)
        if k in fridge:
            total_calories += int(calorie)
    print("{} : {}".format(name, total_calories))

#My_Output
#joe : 2375
#mary : 785
#sandy : 2086
#trudy : 875


#Expected_Output
#trudy :  875
#mary :  985
#sandy : 2186
#joe : 2375

#foods.txt
#almonds 795
#apple pie 405
#asparagus 15
#avocdo 340
#banana 105
#blackberries 75
#blue cheese 100
#blueberries 80
#muffin 135
#blueberry pie 380
#broccoli 40
#butter 100
#cabbage 15
#carrot cake 385
#cheddar cheese 115
#cheeseburger 525
#cherry pie 410
#chicken noodle soup 75
#chocolate chip cookie 185
#cola 160
#cranberry juice 145
#croissant 235
#danish pastry 235
#egg 75
#grapefruit juice 95
#ice cream 375
#lamb 315
#lemon meringue pie 355
#lettuce 5
#macadamia nuts 960
#mayonnaise 100
#mixed grain bread 65
#orange juice 110
#potatoes 120
#pumpkin pie 320
#rice 230
#salmon 150
#spaghetti 190
#spinach 55
#strawberries 45
#taco 195
#tomatoes 25
#tuna 135
#veal 230
#waffles 205
#watermelon 50
#white bread 65
#wine 75
#yogurt 230
#zuchini 16

#sys.stdin
#joe,almonds,almonds,blue cheese,cabbage,mayonnaise,cherry pie,cola
#mary,apple pie,avocado,broccoli,butter,danish pastry,lettuce,apple
#sandy,zuchini,yogurt,veal,tuna,taco,pumpkin pie,macadamia nuts,brazil nuts
#trudy,waffles,waffles,waffles,chicken noodle soup,chocolate chip cookie
```

Comment: I don't know python, but I think using `array.sort();` should help: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered in Python. If you need a dictionary that is ordered, lookup OrderedDict.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dictionaries: How to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/dictionaries-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Answer (score 0):

In the last statement of your code, instead of printing append the values to a list predefined using *list.append((name,totalcalories))*.
Later define a takeSecond function
*def takeSecond(elem):
    return elem[1]*
and sort the list using
*l.sort(key=takeSecond)*
Now you may get your required result.